# Jquery UI DIalog margin too far to the right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog that pops up on a form submit. It looks fine if the content is a small width, however, as the text grows, the left margin of the dialog is too far to the right. I need it to always be center, no matter the size of the content within it.

The markup:

```
<div id="dialog_confirm">
    <p style="font-size:20px; color:white;"></p>
</div>
```

The jquery:

```
$('#dialog_confirm').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: "auto",
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        },
        buttons: {
            'Confirm': {
                text: 'Confirm',
                id: 'confirm_button',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            'Cancel': {
                text: 'Cancel',
                id: 'cancel_button',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The 'width: auto' part makes the content fit the dialog widget properly, but how can I make it where it will always be center with longer text?

[image: Just Fine]

[image: Not Fine!]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it. In my CSS:

```
#dialog_confirm, .ui-dialog{margin-left: -15%;}
```

I just picked an arbitrary number to test and it seems to work. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to chime in. For now, this is working.